# Draw Tikz Triangle (Complex for me)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having a hard time here. I am trying to make this triangle look like the one I draw on the Paper. But but I am not sure how i can implemantate the missing lines and angles?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25]%,cap=round,>=latex]

\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-1.5cm,-1.cm);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (C) at (1.5cm,-1.0cm);
\coordinate [label=above:$C$] (B) at (1.5cm,1.0cm);
\draw (A) -- node[sloped,above] {b} (B) -- node[right] {a = Rundetårn} (C) -- node[below] {$c=\num{20}$} (A);

\draw (1.25cm,-1.0cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-0.75cm);
\tkzMarkAngle[fill= gray,size=0.8cm,opacity=.2](C,A,B)
\tkzLabelAngle[pos = 0.6](C,A,B){$61^0$}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: the package tkz-euclide is the perfect package to do this.

Comment: What are the numbers without degrees?

Comment: The numbers without degrees os meters

Comment: how come 90 = 126?

Comment: So something on the right is 56 Meters? But what exactly is? The dashed line or the solid line to the left and right? Or the solid one across from it?

Comment: No sorry everything is in degrees! my fault!
But 90 isnt = 126 but it is some different angles the 56 on the left side could be left out it is just to show there is 56 degrees

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's haw it can be done with the help of the *calc* library and the *pic* mechanism (and therefore the *angles* and *quotes* libraries):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, angles, quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define A, B and C
    \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- ++ (8,0) coordinate(B) -- ++ (0,6) coordinate (C) -- cycle;

    % go to the point 40% on the way from C to A, name it D; from there go to the intersection from a horizontal line through A and a vertical line through D, call it E
    \draw[dashed] ($(C)!0.4!(A)$) coordinate (D) -- (A -| D) coordinate (E);

    % connect E and C
    \draw (E) -- (C);

    % draw the angle at A; point are specified in negative direction (clockwise)
    \path pic [draw, "$46^{\circ}$", angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=B--A--C};

    % draw the angle at E
    \path pic [draw, "$54^{\circ}$", angle radius=1.2cm] {angle=B--E--C};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! do you know how to get the 90 angle and 126 angle on too ?

Comment: The same as the other paths; for 90° the points are `D--E--A`, for 126° its `C--E--A`. Probably you should alter the `angle radius` for one of them, otherwise they're partially drawn on top of each other.